# Deprecated function get_user_by_email($email)

Tags: functions, email, deprecation

I tried to find replacement function for get_user_by_email($email) but no luck. This function I am using to allow user to log in by email address or user id. Is there any replacement function or alternate way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) is the replacement for `get_user_by_email`:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@email.com' );
```

Comment: one question how can I assign 2nd value (user@email.com) with dynamic variable so it will consider email for whoever login

Comment: here is my function. will it work properly? `function login_with_email_address($username) {
 $user = get_user_by( 'email', $user->user_email );
 //$user = get_user_by_email($username);
 if(!empty($user->user_login))
  $username = $user->user_login;
 return $username;
}`